# Telegram Bot Inlinekeyboard , on callback another inlinekeyboard

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

In my python telegram bot, I am able to display the first inlinekeyboard but How can I display the second Inlinekeyboard in the bot after clicking in the first Inlinekeyboard menu.

```
def start(bot, update):
    sub = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton("AAA", callback_data='0'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("BBB", callback_data='1')]
        ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(sub)
    update.message.reply_text('Select Branch:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(bot, update):

    subK = [
            InlineKeyboardButton("JJJ", callback_data='0'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("HHH", callback_data='1')
        ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(subK)

    query = update.callback_query

    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                          message_id=query.message.message_id,
                          reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())


    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                          message_id=query.message.message_id,
                          reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have added the button() function to the CallbackHandler()?
Than you could use an if statement to check the callback_data (if the new keyboard depends on the button that is pressed)

Maybe it's just the second pair of brackets missing in subK?

```
def button(bot, update):

    subK = [[
            InlineKeyboardButton("JJJ", callback_data='0'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("HHH", callback_data='1')
        ]]
```

The ReplyKeyboardRemove seems not be needed in this snipped, but maybe it's related to ReplyKeyboards created elsewhere? But ReplyKeyboard != InlineKeyboard.